# jni- extract pixels with bitmap.h and store them in 3D array not working

Tags: c, image-processing, bitmap, java-native-interface, native

I wanna pass a bitmap to native, extract the pixels with the help of bitmap.h, than store the pixels in 3D array( x and y and color channel), do some processing on the array by calling other c functions, when done, I write back the array to pixels of bitmap. The problem is: I can extract the pixels but I can't store them in an array. also If you can tell me how to write back array to bitmap's pixels.

My c code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "libimageprocessing"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

static void process(AndroidBitmapInfo* info, void* pixels){
    int xx, yy, red, green, blue;
    int w = info->width;
    int h = info->height;
    uint32_t* line;
    int rgb[h][w][3];
    for(yy = 0; yy < info->height; yy++){
            line = (uint32_t*)pixels;
            for(xx =0; xx < info->width; xx++){

                red =  (int) ((line[xx] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                green = (int)((line[xx] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                blue = (int) (line[xx] & 0x00000FF );

        red = 255 - red;
        green = 255 - green;
        blue = 255 - blue ;

        rgb[yy][xx][0] = red; ////THIS LINE CAUSES THE CRASH, If removed the app returns the inverted image. I WANT TO IMPLEMENT SUCH THING, THEN I DON'T KNOW HOW TO WRITE IT BACK TO BITMAP PIXELS.



        line[xx] =
          ((red << 16) & 0x00FF0000) |
          ((green << 8) & 0x0000FF00) |
          (blue & 0x000000FF);
            }

            pixels = (char*)pixels + info->stride;
        }
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ibm_MainActivity_process(JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj, jobject bitmap)
{
     AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
        int ret;
        void* pixels;

        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
                LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
                return;
            }
        if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
            LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888 !");
            return;
        }

        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
            LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        }
        process(&info,pixels);

        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: `rgb` is just a pointer. Where you allocate space for the array? Forgot a `malloc`? Triple star programmer is not a compliment, what you would do with `uint32_t*** rgb;` You understood that this is declaring an array of pointers to pointers of `uint32`? And maybe you want an array of `char`?

Comment: I edited the code to use rgb[][][]. same thing.

Comment: How big is the bitmap? It might be too big to create an array on the stack, causing stack overflow.

Comment: It's about 2000*1500 @samgak

Comment: Try to create bitmap using dynamic memory, maybe you're experiencing a ... **stack-overflow**

Comment: @Frankie_C Can you show me how to create bitmap using dynamic memory? It'll be much appreciated :)

Comment: `int *rgb[w][3] = malloc(sizeof(int)*h*w*3);`

Comment: Tried it. It works.  But it's somehow slow when adding loops for allocating and freeing the memory.